# shorter way to delete key from a dictionary

Tags: python

I have wanted to delete the taste key from the line_items dict list of the entire dictionary list. the code is given below

```
  orders = [
    {
    'order_id' : 1,
    'line_items': [
                    {
                    'product_id': 2,
                    'product_name' : 'mango',
                    'taste' : 'sweet',

                    },

                    {
                    'product_id':3,
                    'product_name': 'grape',
                    'taste': 'sweet & sour',

                    }
                ],
    },
    {
    'order_id' : 2,
    'line_items': [
                    {
                    'product_id': 4,
                    'product_name' : 'lime',
                    'taste' : 'sour',

                    }
                  ]
    },                  
]
```

I have already done it. and this is my solution.

```
delitems = ['taste']
for order in orders:
    for item in order["line_items"]:
        for delkeys in delitems:
            item.pop(delkeys)
```

But I think it is a bad code and wanted to know if is there any way to shorting my code
with dict comprehension or another way?

Comment: You want a very specific operation: delete the given list of keys of the object _A_ in the key _B_ that is a list. I guess it's natural to have this code size. You can just wrap it in a function to make it easier to re-use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly more natural than using `dict.pop` when you don't care about the value you're deleting would be to use the `del` statement:

```
del item[delkeys]
```

Obviously, this doesn't reduce the number of lines. If you're only ever deleting the one key, you don't need the `delitems` and the loop over it. If you don't mind hard-coding that `"taste"` is the key to delete, just do:

```
for order in orders:
    for item in order["line_items"]:
        del item["taste"]
```

While you could write a bunch of nested list comprehension and dictionary comprehensions to achieve the same effect in a single statement, it would be a lot harder to understand than your simple nested loop code.

Comment: yep, i think so. Coz code readability is much important.

Answer (score 1):

```
for order in orders:
    for item in order["line_items"]:
        del item["taste"]
```